# Delete Duplicate rows while grouping another one

Tags: mysql

I have got a problem here which I could not solve with google. I got table a with rows number and parameter. Now I want to remove duplicated rows with the same parameter for each number:

```
Number    Parameter  id
3         22         1
3         22         2
2         32         3
1         44         4
2         12         5
4         22         6
1         44         7
2         12         8
2         36         9
```

to

```
Number    Parameter  id
3         22         1
2         32         3
1         44         4
2         12         5
4         22         6
2         36         9
```

I tried

`DELETE n1 FROM a n1,a n2 WHERE n1.parameter = n2.parameter AND n1.id > n2.id AND n1.id <> n2.id`

But this deletes every row with duplicated parameter so that only one of each is kept. I need to somehow add Group by Number. I think but I dont know how.

EDIT: Oh i missed to add the ID row. Ofcourse every row has a ID row i will add it now.

EDIT2: answer from 10086 worked!

Comment: as long as the duplicated rows are exactly the same, not even a single column has different value, then I think removing one is impossible. Instead, why don't you use distinct? select distinct number, parameter from table;

Comment: As andre_northwind sais, it is impossible to remove one of the rows, which are exactly the same. You need at least one extra column. Can you change the table's schema?

Answer (score 0):

Try following;)

```
DELETE t1
FROM a t1
INNER JOIN a t2
ON t1.id > t2.id
AND t1.Parameter = t2.Parameter
AND t1.Number = t2.Number;
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fad9a/1)

It will remain the row with the lowest id value.

Comment: @Baldry Updated, please try it again. And check the SQLFiddle demo there.

Comment: Worked like a Charm Thank you very much! i will have to look into the data more to be sure but it seems right.